# Specific number of points within each polygon of a shape in R

Tags: r, gis, shapes, point-in-polygon

I have a shapefile with around 400 polygons of different sizes. I have been trying to create a random point layer with a specific number of points within each of the 400 polygons.

I tried with  `spsample`  function but it generates a random layer of points that does not respect each polygon (it is a general random point layers of the total shapefile).

As an example:

[Shape file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV7DS.png)

Download: biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/USA_adm.zip

it is the file "USA_adm1"

This shapefile contains 52 polygons.   I am looking to put a specific number of random points inside every one of the 52 polygons. For example a random distribution of 100 points inside each of the states.

I hope you can help me.

thank you

Comment: please provide a sample of your polygon data, otherwise its hard to help.

Comment: hello @dvd280  I just upload the data.

Answer (score 2):

From the `sf` package using `st_sample` on an sf object:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# using data included with sf package,
#  it contains 100 polygons
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# st_sample needs a vector telling it how many samples for each polygon
#  here we're using 3 for each polygon
samples_per_polygon <- rep(3, nrow(nc))

samples <- st_sample(nc, samples_per_polygon)


ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nc) + geom_sf(data = samples)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do I feel like the `sf::point_on_surface()` function should have two additional parameters to randomize the placement of the point(s) and to specify how many points?